Harmonic and homogeneous function
I am trying to find all harmonic functions in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with homogeneous degree 5. I do not know how to combine the condition $$u(tx)=t^5 u(x)$$ with $\Delta u=0$.

Consider the spherical coordinate
$$
  x=r\sin\phi\cos\theta,\ y=r\sin\phi\sin\theta,\ z=r\cos\phi\quad \mbox{for}\ \  r\ge0, \phi\in[0,\pi], \theta\in[0,2\pi].
$$
The Laplace equation is represented as
$$
  \Delta_{x,y,z}u = \frac{1}{r^2}(r^2u_r)_r + \frac{1}{r^2\sin\phi}(\sin\phi \ u_{\phi})_{\phi} + \frac{1}{r^2\sin^2\phi}u_{\theta\theta}=0.\quad (1)
$$
By the homogeneity of $u$, that is, $u(tr,\phi,\theta) = t^5u(r,\phi,\theta)$, one gets, $u_r = \frac{5}{r}u$. Substituting the formula into $(1)$, we obtain
$$
  30u + \frac{1}{\sin\phi}(\sin\phi \ u_{\phi})_{\phi} + \frac{1}{\sin^2\phi}u_{\theta\theta}=0.\quad (2)
$$
It follows that $u(r,\phi,\theta)=f(r)v(\phi,\theta)$ and $f(tr)=t^5f(r)$. As for $v(\phi,\theta)$, assume that $v(\phi,\theta)=\Phi(\phi)\Theta(\theta)$, by $(2)$, we have
$$
  \frac{\Theta''}{\Theta}=-\frac{1}{\Phi}(\sin^2\phi\ \Phi''+\cos\phi\sin\phi\ \Phi'+30\sin^2\phi\ \Phi).\quad (3)
$$
Clearly, $v(\phi,\theta) = v(\phi,\theta+2\pi)$, then $\frac{\Theta''}{\Theta}=\lambda=-n^2$ for $n\ge0$. It yields $\Theta(\theta)=a_n\cos (n\theta) + b_n\sin (n\theta)$ for $a_n,b_n\in\mathbb{R}$. For clarity, we denote $\Theta,\Phi$ by $\Theta_n,\Phi_n$ corresponding to $\lambda=-n^2$. Moreover, $\Phi_n$ satisfies
$$
  -\frac{1}{\Phi_n}(\sin^2\phi\ \Phi_n''+\cos\phi\sin\phi\ \Phi_n'+30\sin^2\phi\ \Phi_n)=-n^2,
$$
that is,
$$
  \sin^2\phi\ \Phi_n''+\cos\phi\sin\phi\ \Phi_n'+(30\sin^2\phi-n^2)\ \Phi_n=0.\quad (4)
$$
Using mathematica, we obtain
$$
  \Phi_n = c_n P_5^n(\cos\phi) + d_n Q_5^n(\cos\phi),\ \ c_n,d_n\in\mathbb{R}\quad (5)
$$
where $P_5^n$ and $Q_5^n$ are LegendreP and LegendreQ polynomials. As a result, each of the harmonic solution with homogeneous degree 5 is represented as
$$
  u(r,\phi,\theta)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f_n(r)\Phi_n(\phi)\Theta_n(\theta).
$$
Here $f_n(tr)=t^5f_n(r),\ \Theta_n(\theta)=a_n\cos (n\theta) + b_n\sin (n\theta)$, and $\Phi_n = c_n P_5^n(\cos\phi) + d_n Q_5^n(\cos\phi)$ for $a_n,b_n,c_n,d_n\in\mathbb{R}$.

This can also be done using the analyticity of harmonic functions. We show that $u$ must be a polynomial. For a multi-index $\alpha$ with $|\alpha|\ne 5$, we have, for $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$,
\begin{equation*}
    \lambda^{|\alpha|} D^\alpha u(\lambda x) = \lambda^5 D^\alpha u(x).
\end{equation*}
Choosing $\lambda = 2$ and $x = 0$, we see that $D^\alpha u(0) = 0$, since $2^{|\alpha|}\ne 2^5$. Thus,
\begin{equation*}
    u(x) = \sum_{|\alpha| = 5} c_\alpha X^\alpha.
\end{equation*}
The upshot of doing it this way is that this method works for $\mathbb{R}^n$ for all $n\ge 2$.
